# N-Queens Symmetry Breaking Google OR Tools

Tags: python, n-queens, symmetry, or-tools

[One of the samples for the Google or-tools is a solver for the n-queens problem.](https://developers.google.com/optimization/puzzles/queens)  At the bottom it says that the implementation can be improved by adding symmetry breaking constraints to the constraint solver.

Looking around the internet, [I found the symmetry breaking constraints for the n-queens problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6iZXVkfLQAhWFYyYKHVsbCbYQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fta.twi.tudelft.nl%2Fwst%2Fusers%2Fachill%2FMFOSymOpt2010%2FMFOSymOpt2010%2FOberwolfach_Mini-Workshop_files%2FBarbaraMfoSlides.ppt&usg=AFQjCNGr3D2IOBqH2H_uKGMpfacqROKGEA&sig2=cPjZSKepUE9t-hRaz-xtRw&bvm=bv.141536425,d.eWE), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert those to constraints to python code that implements them.

---

EDIT: this was a bad question, let's update...

What have I tried?

Here is the setup from the first link above:

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

N = 8
solver = pywrapcp.Solver("n-queens")
# Creates the variables.
# The array index is the column, and the value is the row.
queens = [solver.IntVar(0, N - 1, "x%i" % i) for i in range(N)]
# Creates the constraints.
# All rows must be different.
solver.Add(solver.AllDifferent(queens))
# All columns must be different because the indices of queens are all different.
# No two queens can be on the same diagonal.
solver.Add(solver.AllDifferent([queens[i] + i for i in range(N)]))
solver.Add(solver.AllDifferent([queens[i] - i for i in range(N)]))

# TODO: add symmetry breaking constraints

db = solver.Phase(queens, solver.CHOOSE_FIRST_UNBOUND, solver.ASSIGN_MIN_VALUE)
solver.NewSearch(db)
num_solutions = 0
while solver.NextSolution():
  num_solutions += 1
solver.EndSearch()
print()
print("Solutions found:", num_solutions)
print("Time:", solver.WallTime(), "ms")
```

I know I can implement simple constraints successfully.  If I wanted to ensure the solution always has a queen in the first column on the first row, I could implement that like this:

```
solver.Add(queens[0] == 0)
```

The `queens[0]` variable represents the queens location in the first column and this constraint is only satisfied when the first column has a queen in the first row.  This of course is not what I want to do however because it's possible that a solution does not include any corner cells.

The symmetry breaking constraints for the n-queens problem are found below.  They are pulled directly from the link in the second paragraph.

[image: n-queens symmetry breaking constraints]

I understand how these constraints work.  The idea is that you can apply this function to each cell on the n-queens board in order to transform the state into an equivalent state.  One of these states will be the canonical representation of that state.  This is used as a method to prune future processing by eliminating duplicate evaluations.

If I were just implementing this in an after the fact way, I would do exactly what I describe above, convert the state using each possible symmetry breaking function, calculate some sort of state hash (e.g. a string of the selected row in each column) and select the one that's the lowest for each proposed solution.  Skip future processing on ones we have seen before.

**My problem is that I don't know how to convert these transformations into constraints for the google or-tools constraint programming solver.**

Let's take a look at the simplest one, `d1(r[i] = j) => r[j] = i`, reflection about the main diagonal.  What I know is that the transformation needs to be applied to all cells, then compared against the current state in order to prevent one from being expanded.  I don't understand enough about python to understand what kind of expression works here for the transformation, and I just can't figure out how to create the constraint that compares the transformation to the current state for this particular solver.

```
state = [queens[i].Value() for i in range(N)]
symX    = [state[N - (i + 1)] for i in range(N)]
symY    = [N - (state[i] + 1) for i in range(N)]
symD1   = [state.index(i) for i in range(N)]
symD2   = [N - (state.index(N-(i+1)) + 1) for i in range(N)]
symR90  = [N - (state.index(i) + 1) for i in range(N)]
symR180 = [N - (state[N-(i+1)] + 1) for i in range(N)]
symR270 = [state.index(N-(i+1)) for i in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use a custom DecisionBuilder to prune the search tree using the symmetries as new constraints, but I couldn't make it work.

Instead I had to use a SearchMonitor that captures the event of every solution and check if that solution is a symmetry of a previous one.

Here i add the code of the SearchMonitor, the capture of the solution overriding the "AcceptSolution" function, and the gen_symetries function to calculate and check all possible symmetries.

```
    class SearchMonitor(pywrapcp.SearchMonitor):
    def __init__(self, solver, q):
        pywrapcp.SearchMonitor.__init__(self, solver)
        self.q = q
        self.all_solutions = []
        self.unique_solutions = []
        self.n = len(self.q)

    def AcceptSolution(self):
        qval = [self.q[i].Value() for i in range(self.n)]
        self.all_solutions.append(qval)

        symmetries = [vv in self.unique_solutions for vv in gen_symmetries(self.n, qval)]

        if sum(symmetries) == 0:
            self.unique_solutions.append(qval)

        return False

def gen_symmetries(n, solution):
    symmetries = []

    #x(r[i]=j) → r[n−i+1]=j
    x = list(range(n))
    for index in range(n):
        x[n - 1 - index] = solution[index]

    symmetries.append(x)

    #y(r[i]=j) → r[i]=n−j+1
    y = list(range(n))
    for index in range(n):
        y[index] = (n - 1 - solution[index])

    symmetries.append(y)

    #d1(r[i]=j) → r[j]=i
    d1 = list(range(n))
    for index in range(n):
        d1[solution[index]] = index

    symmetries.append(d1)

    # d2(r[i]=j) → r[n−j+1]=n−i+1
    d2 = list(range(n))
    for index in range(n):
        d2[n - 1 - solution[index]] = (n - 1 - index)

    symmetries.append(d2)

    # r90(r[i]=j) → r[j] = n−i+1
    r90 = list(range(n))
    for index in range(n):
        r90[solution[index]] = (n - 1 - index)

    symmetries.append(r90)

    # r180(r[i]=j) → r[n−i+1]=n−j+1
    r180 = list(range(n))
    for index in range(n):
        r180[n - 1 - index] = (n - 1 - solution[index])

    symmetries.append(r180)

    # r270(r[i]=j) → r[n−j+1]=i
    r270 = list(range(n))
    for index in range(n):
        r270[n - 1 - solution[index]] = index

    symmetries.append(r270)

    return symmetries
```

Later you just have to add the monitor to your solver like this.

```
monitor = SearchMonitor(solver, queens)
solver.Solve(db, monitor)
solver.NewSearch(db)
```

And finally just printing all the unique solutions

```
print("Unique Solutions:", len(monitor.unique_solutions), monitor.unique_solutions)
```

You can see the full working example in the gist.

https://gist.github.com/carlgira/7a4e6cf0f7b7412762171015917bccb4

Answer (score 1):

You must use the known symmetry relations between the sought solutions to identify constraints that will eliminate equivalent solutions.

1. For every solution with `queens[0] >= N/2`, then there is another, vertically mirrored, solution with `queens[0] <= N/2`. Therefore, we can seek for the solution with the smaller value of `queens[0]` and add the following constraint:

   ```
   solver.Add(queens[0] < (N+1)//2) # Handle both even and odd values of N
   ```
2. Then, a solution satisfying the condition `queens[0] < queens[N-1]` has an equivalent, horizontally-mirrored, solution satisfying `queens[0] > queens[N-1]`. You can tell the solver to look for only those solutions, where the queen in the leftmost column is below the queen in the rightmost column:

   ```
   solver.Add(queens[0] < queens[N-1])
   ```

I couldn't easily formulate a constraint reflecting the rotational symmetry, but I believe that it is possible.